# Powershell: Find specifc string/line from text file and -Replace unnecessary part from it / remove everything before

Tags: powershell

I'd like to make Powershell script which get specific string from the line. This string might be on different lines. So text file looks like this -
1st file -

```
[Bootstrap]
buildid=400m3(Build:9702)
ProductBuildid=9702
ProductCode={55E61709-D7D4-43C0-B45D-BFAF5C09A02D}
UpgradeCode={7C35B9AB-2CE3-4C18-BE7C-5B97EA089EB3}
```

2nd file -

```
[Bootstrap]
ProductCode={2BB8FBB4-CFF9-434E-AA0A-40F5379C1602}
```

I need to get MSI code after ProductCode=

```
$openofficeSetup = "C:\Program Files (x86)\openoffice*\program\setup.ini"
if (Test-Path $openofficeSetup)
{
$openofficeMSI = Select-String "ProductCode=*" $openofficeSetup
$openofficeMSI = $openofficeMSI -Replace "*ProductCode=", ""
msiexec.exe /x $openofficeMSI /qn
```

Line 5 with -Replace is wrong. i have no idea how to remove everything before.

```
PS N:\> echo $openofficeMSI
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\setup.ini:4:ProductCode={55E61709-D7D4-43C0-B45D-BFAF5C09A02D}
```

How can I get rid of everything but MSI code?

Offtopic: Other way would searching for MSI code in registry 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\
but using setup.ini looks easier.

Comment: MSI code has 38 characters. Maybe simply I should grab last 38 characters then...

Comment: Paths can't contain asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [regex]::Match instead of select-string:

```
$openofficeSetup = Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\openoffice*\program\setup.ini" 
if (Test-Path $openofficeSetup){
  $txt=[IO.File]::ReadAllText($openofficeSetup )
  $openofficeMSI = [regex]::Match($txt,'ProductCode=(.*)').Groups[1].Value
  msiexec.exe /x $openofficeMSI /qn
}
```

Comment: I got an error, sorry it is in German:
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ReadAllText" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Illegales Zeichen im Pfad."
Bei Zeile:3 Zeichen:28
+ $txt=[IO.File]::ReadAllText <<<< ($openofficeSetup)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: "Illegales Zeichen im Pfad" means "illegal character in path," i.e., the asterisk.

Comment: I missed the asterisk in the path. Yes, ReadAllText doesn't like wildcards. Resolve-Path to the rescue